# Camel-casing a 'dashed' string

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, string-manipulation

I'm fairly inexperienced with *nix scripting, and I have a need to take a string with lowercase words separated by dashes and convert that to a new string with the dashes removed, and the first letter after each original dash uppercased.  For example, I want to take

`one-two-three-four-five`

and convert it to

`oneTwoThreeFourFive`

The solution must be able to handle multiple dashes (including none), and can use other *nix utilities if necessary like sed, awk, etc.

Comment: What do you mean be "including none" - that would just be the original word... onetwo-three would be onetwoThree

Comment: @BigChris I think OP simply means that the proposed solution cannot assume that any dashes are present at all, and must gracefully handle that case.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling And split the words for him? Gee, I'll pass on this one.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - That's correct.  If I were to pass in the string 'baseball' the solution must return that untouched ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
echo one-two-three-four-five | perl -pe 's/-(.)/\u$1/g'
```

`\u` upcases the following character.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Tested on MacOS (El Capitan).

Comment: Also tested on Debian Wheezy and works like a charm.